# What kind of RC filter is this?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter

[image: RC filterstrong text]

For an ADC(ADS52J90) the datasheet suggests this filter as a high-pass filter for the input of the converter, but I did not managed to understand this filter. Is it a high-pass filter? Is it used commonly? (I didn't find this in my filter design books)

Is this filter affected, if a place an ac-coupling capacitor before it? My band of interest is 25-35MHz and I choose the coupling capacitor according to it.

Comment: That doesn't look like a high-pass to me. It looks like a low-pass, but barely. At low frequencies, the capacitor looks like an open and it does nothing. At high frequencies the capacitor looks like a short and the signal sees 100R in shunt, which attenuates it... a little.

Comment: This filter dump the high frequencies. Of course you can place a series cap to remove DC or low frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is what the datasheet is saying, if you're looking at 8.3.12.1. It is the ac coupling capacitors in fig 89 that form the high pass filter with the resistors across the diff pair.  For DC coupling, figure 90, no such filter exists... having a high pass filter in a directly coupled circuit doesn't make sense.  I would suggest that the circuit you've simulated is just line termination for ac content.  Maybe give your model a tweak to see the difference between the ac and dc circuits.  [image: from_datasheet]